# Cant seem to file share between cloned drives

Tags: hard-drive, airdrop, carbon-copy-cloner

Im running two macs on my home office setup; a 2010 Macbook Pro and a 2011 Mac Mini. Both have been upgraded in the past with Crucial SSDs and for each I used the Carbon Copy software to clone the drives before installation. I noticed the other night I couldn't Airdrop between my two machines. I figured this must have something to do with the clone and was wondering if there was a workaround to fix this issue?

Ive also noticed issues in the past with apps like iMessage not updating on both machines, only one or the other.

For the time being Dropbox does the trick, but having Airdrop operational between the two would be ideal. Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify - 1) did airdrop work before you cloned the machines? 2) Is each a separate clone of "itself" or are they both clones of one Mac? 3) What OS is on each Mac? 2012 was kind of a break-point in AirDrop protocols so these machines may be on the cusp of two different protocols - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirDrop also https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/06/23/how-to-mac-compatible-airdrop/

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. 1) yes, airdrop worked on the macbook pro, which was the 'parent' drive all other drives were cloned from. 2) all drives are a clone of each other, so A was used to clone B which was used to clone C and so on. 3) They are both currently running Sierra 10.12 - which is where they are both capped at as I cant seem to upgrade any further. Gotta love legacy systems

Comment: OK, then see Gilby's answer - they may all be identifying as the 'same Mac'. All the Macs here are spawned from the same origin drive, but do behave as individuals in all respects. btw, no Mac should be stuck on Sierra. High Sierra was a break-point, dependent on your GPU capabilities; Mojave demanded Metal2 capability.  https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility has a guide.

Comment: Tetsujin, looks like you had the answer. I checked both my systems and they were on different OS versions. I got them both running HS now and that fixed the Airdrop issue. It also seemed to fix the issue with the iApps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cloning is intended to provide an identical copy of the system. That is great for disaster recovery, but not so good for running on another computer unless you perform some extra steps.  You have two identical software configurations (possibly even with the same computer name) and that causes confusion.

If you don't want to start from scratch on one of the Macs, you need to rename and reset one of the Macs.

As a start, I would give Macs different names (do this in System Preferences > Sharing). Reboot. Then remove one from iCloud and re-add it. Again, reboot.  That may be all that is needed - you will need to tell us!

Those two steps should enable iCloud (for iMessage, etc) and local network services (e.g. AirDrop) to recognise them as separate computers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Ill give this a try tonight and follow up on the results. Cheers!

Comment: After checking my machines they had already been renamed and updated with iCloud. Appears the issue was one was running High Sierra and the other just Sierra. Once I updated both machines they now work as expected. Thanks for the suggestion!